# Google Stats, how to get More info?

Tags: google-analytics

I have created a blog very recently and i'm seeing my traffic and audience using Google Stats that is in built in google blogger. I have few question on google stats:

> 1) Is number of visitor shown by stat
>   is rough or accurate?
>
> 2) How i do find whether people have
>   visited my site or search engines?
>
> 3) Is google stats is best for
>   beginners like me? or any other tool?

Correct me if am wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Stats is not in official name I believe.

Anyway it is ROUGH , the data HIGHLY incomplete , I have my own blog there and I have an Google Analytics account and on comparison of data , you will find surprisingly MAJOR differences .

Even if you are an amateur , Google Analytics (The World's most popular JavaScript) is the best !

Sing up here http://www.google.com/analytics/

Answer to Question #2 can be found in Visitors Overview of Google Analytics dashboard.

And yes it is good for beginners.

Comment: after seeing your blog, i have seen "adsense" support has been activated in your blog. Is it easy to earn money via adsense? ^_^ ??

Comment: yes and a no . Adsense is directly related with traffic . I get 6,128 page views with just 15 clicks and my CPC is around 1$ so I get 10 - 15 $ a month !

Answer (score 0):

Don't restrict yourself to just Google Analytics, there is many more on the market.

1. [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/)
2. [Woopra](http://www.woopra.com/)
3. [Mint](http://haveamint.com/)
4. [Clicky](http://imimpact.com/getclicky)
5. [StatCounter](http://statcounter.com/)
6. [Reinvigorate](http://www.reinvigorate.net/)
7. [PiWiki](http://piwik.org/)
8. [Open Web Analytics](http://www.openwebanalytics.com)
9. [Chart Beat](http://chartbeat.com)
10. [Mix Panel](http://mixpanel.com)
11. [Kiss Metrics](http://www.kissmetrics.com/)
12. [Fox Metrics](http://foxmetrics.com/)
13. [Going Up](http://www.goingup.com/)
14. [Engine Ready](http://www.engineready.com/)