# How to track hot-linking of image types in IIS7

Tags: google-analytics, asp.net, tracking, iis7, hotlinking

I don't want to block hot-linking on my site; it's not that big a deal. However, Google Analytics doesn't show me referrers to png/gif/jpg content; I don't have any statistics on the load generated from external sites due to hotlinking. Is there a way I can have Google Analytics track those files? If not, are there any alternative software that can make this task easier than manually parsing through IIS7 logs?

Comment: I don't know of any ready-made software for this task. But it shouldn't be too complicated to write a little script that counts the requests for this images files in the IIS7 logs and produces some kind of statistics from it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a master of IIS7 so my response will be pretty limited, through it'll use some logic based on what I do.

I don't use Google to track hotlinking, I use various of other applications such as:

> [SOURCE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15174/google-stats-how-to-get-more-info/39056#39056)
>
> 1. [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/)
> 2. [Woopra](http://www.woopra.com/)
> 3. [Mint](http://haveamint.com/)
> 4. [Clicky](http://imimpact.com/getclicky)
> 5. [StatCounter](http://statcounter.com/)
> 6. [Reinvigorate](http://www.reinvigorate.net/)
> 7. [PiWiki](http://piwik.org/)
> 8. [Open Web Analytics](http://www.openwebanalytics.com)
> 9. [Chart Beat](http://chartbeat.com)
> 10. [Mix Panel](http://mixpanel.com)
> 11. [Kiss Metrics](http://www.kissmetrics.com/)
> 12. [Fox Metrics](http://foxmetrics.com/)
> 13. [Going Up](http://www.goingup.com/)
> 14. [Engine Ready](http://www.engineready.com/)

I'm not sure how many if any of these will work on the IIS platform. However another way of tracking hotlinks is using backlink trackers, embedding a image of any type or any file for that matter is a backlink, you're be able to track your links using good backlink firms such as:

1. [Majestic Seo](http://www.majesticseo.com/) (free for site owners, just verify your site).
2. [SEO Profiler](http://www.seoprofiler.com/)

Comment: Stuffed Tracker seems to have been abandoned; no updates since 2006 and their domain name has expired. You sure you use it?

Comment: That was just a quote from an answer in another thread, I'll delete that entry thanks.